# Read wav in python by mili seconds

Tags: python, audio, wave

I need to cut from wav files small pieces (phonemes), which are about 0.1 seconds (e.g. 0.3698125 - 0.466125

I'm using wave module, but it can't handle it :-/ Does anybody know how to handle it?

This script should open file, cut the piece and add it to the new one

```
data = fonemy[fonem][0] = start, end, path ([0.3698125, 0.466125, u'hds/data/speech_16kHz/utt001.wav'])

frames = ""
text   = "hello"     
for fonem in text:
    data = fonemy[fonem][0]
    win = wave.open(data[2], 'rb')
    wout = wave.open('segment.wav', 'wb')
    wout.setparams(win.getparams())
    t0 = data[0]
    t1= data[1]
    s0, s1= int(t0*win.getframerate()), int(t1*win.getframerate())
    win.readframes(s0) # discard
    frames = frames + win.readframes(s1-s0)

wout.writeframes(frames)
```

Comment: this looks good, actually. what do you mean by *but it can't handle it*? what is the expected result and what do you get?

Comment: i need audio sample from 0.3698125 to 0.466125, this function just doesn't work, it takes ints, so begin and end of the sample is 0 - it will read nothing

Comment: can you please show what `print t0, t1, win.getframerate()` returns?

Comment: for one iteration 0.3698125 0.466125 16000 - framerate is still the same, only time is changing

Comment: `int(0.3698125*16000) == 5917`. so what do you mean by *"begin and end of sample is 0"*?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by 'it can't handle it', but one problem here is that you're trying to read frames using a `float`, but you can only read an integral number of frames:

```
>>> w = wave.open("/Users/bgporter/Documents/Juce Demo Audio Recording.wav", "rb")
>>> rate = w.getframerate()
>>> frames = 0.3698125 * rate
>>> w.readframes(frames)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line 253, in readframes
    data = self._data_chunk.read(nframes * self._framesize)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/chunk.py", line 134, in read
    data = self.file.read(size)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/chunk.py", line 134, in read
    data = self.file.read(size)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

It's not meaningful to read part of an audio sample. Figure out if you want one more or one less frame worth of data and round to the next higer or lower frame number as appropriate:

```
>>> data = w.readframes(int(frames))
>>> len(data)
32616
```

Comment: sorry, i was trying if it can take float and forget to rewrite it back to int...

problem is, i need exact data from 0.3698125 to 0.466125 for letter h, if i will use int, begin and end is 0, so it will cut nothing :-/

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Assuming a sampling rate of 44100Hz, 44100*3698125 = 16308.73 and .466125*44100 = 20556.1125. If you round start down and end up, you'd extract 20557-16308 = 4249 frames worth of data.